# image of the canonical morphism of a spanned divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Take $S$ a complex algebraic projective surface and $M\in Div(S)$ a spanned divisor of $S$.
Due to the fact that $M$ is spanned we can define a morphism
$\phi_{[M]} :S \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$  with $N=h^0(M)-1$.
What can i say about the image of $S$ through $\phi_{[M]}$? is it a smooth curve?

Comment: i need this because it's a part of the key lemma of the theory of minimal models due to castelnuovo enriques. In the proof there is a morphism like in the question but the image of $S$  under $\phi$ is a non singular curve. Can i say that in the hypotesis of the question the image it' a curve?

Comment: The image of $S$ will be a curve if and only if $M$ is not ample.

Comment: Where can i find this?

Comment: It is called the Nakai--Moishezon criterion. It is in many textbooks.